# Is CUDA Toolkit an cuDNN specific to a conda environment?

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04, conda

I somehow managed to setup a conda environment with gpu working. Now I need to make another environment. Simply doing `conda install tensorflow-gpu` does not work in the new environment. Do I need to install CUDA and cuDNN again for this environment? 
I am using Ubuntu 16.04 
CUDA 9.0.176 (using `cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt`) 
cuDNN 7.1.4 (using command `cat /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2`) 
Driver Version: 384.130 (using `nvidia-smi`) 
Please note that `nvcc -version` does not work, it says program is not installed, and I do not have administrator privileges. 
Tensorflow version 1.12.0 is on the environment which works.

Comment: "Please note that nvcc -version does not work" -- that is because conda deosn't install it. The cuda-toolkit package in conda is just a handful of libraries whcih are needed for runtime support of the various GPU accelerated packages they distribute

Comment: CUDA and cuDNN are being installed systemwide so you don't have to install them again. `nvcc --version` does not work because you might have forgot to export it to path. Take a look at here:


https://askubuntu.com/questions/885610/nvcc-version-command-says-nvcc-is-not-installed